# How to convert string to dictionary using split

Tags: python, python-3.x

string = 'racknumber: 1 racktype: rack23 apn: rackansi2p height: 2134.0 width: 701.0'

output = {'racknumber': '1', 'racktype': 'rack23', 'apn': 'rackansi2p', 'height': '2134.0', 'width': '701.0'}

Answer (score 0):

If there is only 1 item per key, you can do like this

```py
mystr = "racknumber: 1 racktype: rack23 apn: rackansi2p height: 2134.0 width: 701.0"
splitted = mystr.split()
mydic = {}

for i in range(len(splitted)):

    if i % 2 == 1:
        mydic[splitted[i-1]] = splitted[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'racknumber: 1 racktype: rack23 apn: rackansi2p height: 2134.0 width: 701.0'

l = sum((s.split() for s in string.split(':')), [])
d = dict(zip(l, l[1:]))
print(d)
```

Remarks:

- flattening lists with `sum( , [])` is not recommended due to time complexity "issues". Use i.e. `chain` from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html). For testing small stuffs on the fly... can be useful, I think.

Here with `itertools`

```
...
l = list(it.chain.from_iterable(s.split() for s in string.split(':')))
...
```

- for more complex stuffs use regular expressions, see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html)

```
import re

d = dict(re.findall(r'\b([^\s]+?):\s([^\s]+)', string))
```